# Set community index as a vertex attribute with IGraph Python

Tags: python, igraph

When I detect communities on a graph with Igraph in Python, I get a result like this:

```
print g.community_multilevel(return_levels=False)

Clustering with 100 elements and 4 clusters
[0] 16, 17, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
    36, 37, 39, 40, 44
[1] 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19, 38, 92, 94, 96,
    97, 98, 99
[2] 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
    61, 62, 63, 64, 66, 67, 69
[3] 21, 41, 65, 68, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83,
    84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 93, 95
```

I'm adding the corresponding community number as an attribute to each vertex like this:

```
for v in g.vs():
    c = 0
    for i in g.community_multilevel(return_levels=False):
        if v.index in i:
            print v.index,i,c
            v["group"] = c
        c += 1
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is terribly inefficient because you are running the community detection algorithm for every single iteration of the outer loop even though its result should be the same no matter how many times you run it. A much simpler way to do it would be:

```
cl = g.community_multilevel(return_levels=False)
g.vs["group"] = cl.membership
```